# Generating 64-bit values with a 32-bit Mersenne Twister

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, random

According to [this Boost documentation page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_random/performance.html), the 64-bit variant of the Mersenne Twister is much slower than its 32-bit counterpart (which makes sense). As I understand, a lot of the features introduced in C++11, including random number generation, are basically Boost in the standard library. This leads me to believe that 32-bit MT performance in standard C++ is also better.

I'm writing a raytracer (for fun, mostly), and speed is one of my primary concerns. Essentially all the numerical values are represented as double precision floats. My question is, since the 32-bit MT is considerably faster, can I use it to generate doubles? What drawbacks (precision loss, performance, etc.) can I expect?

Comment: What does "precision loss" mean in the context of random numbers?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I doubt it. It's up to the *distribution* to accumulate enough entropy. You get the same statistical quality of a distribution with an engine that only produces uniform random numbers in the range 13-17.

Comment: [Recommended STL video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Comment: As in casting from float to double.

Comment: @KerrekSB Interesting point. Can you cite a source?

Comment: @MoreAxes: 25.5.1.6 I suppose.

Comment: @KerrekSB What on *earth* is that?

Comment: A 32-bit Mersene twister never has more than 19,968 bits of entropy unless you add more along the way.

Comment: @MoreAxes: The standard reference - that's the section in the C++11 standard.

Comment: @KerrekSB Oh, sorry. I'm a bit groggy. Is there somewhere I can access it? I can only find paid sources, I would imagine this sort of thing would be publicly accessible.

Comment: @MoreAxes: Yeah, it's [on GitHub](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft) -- that's the current draft, which has evolved a little past C++11, but it's all in there. (You need to run LaTeX yourself on it.)

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm pretty sure you meant 26.5.1.6, since 25.5.1.6 doesn't exist, and section 25 isn't relevant to random number generation. Regardless, unless I'm getting tangled up in wording, the relevant section (the entire 26.5.1, actually) doesn't mention anything about entropy.

Comment: @MoreAxes: There may have been a new section added and I haven't rebuilt since... anyway, the section in question describes the statistical behaviour, which *implies* that sufficient entropy must be gathered. If you had an engine that only produced 0 and 1, then you still expect `uniform_real_distribution` to produce more than two values.

Comment: @kerrek I thought 25.5.1.6 was an IP address!

Answer (score 2):

For this I am adding one assumption that you did not mention: I am assuming you are doing one random draw per double.  Obviously you can get twice the randomness by doing two draws.

The first question is really "does 32-bits of pseudorandomness have enough randomness for my ray tracer."  My guess is yes.  Most raytracers are only shooting out a few million rays, so you wont notice that there's only 4 billion bits of pseudorandomness.

Second question is "can I distribute the pseudorandomness across the domain of double values I care about."  Again, my guess is yes.  If you are shooting rays in a 90 degree field, and there are 4 billion possible results from one pseudorandom draw.  For perspective, a sniper looking through a high power scope sees millions of times less angular precision than the average difference between those pseudorandom vectors.

All that being said, profile your code.  I'd give a 99.9998% chance that your raytracing code itself takes **much** longer than the pseudorandom generation unless your scenes all consist of single non-reflective spheres

Comment: Can you explain how can I get "twice the randomness" from drawing twice?

Comment: I should be more precise, "twice the pseudorandomness"  `int64_t r = rand32() << 32 | rand32()`

Comment: I'm operating on floats/doubles here. Bitwise operations seem... unsafe, given the very sensitive formatting of floats.

Comment: What routine are you using to change the mersene twister output into a float/double then?

Comment: Standard C++11 library facilities. Declare engine `std::mt19937 MT(seed)`, declare distribution `std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0,1)`, then call `dist(MT)` whenever I need a new random double. I don't do seed sequences yet, but it'll happen at some point.

Comment: Ahh, then nevermind what I said.  There are no consequences of mt19937 vs mt19937_64 that are more important than the fact that you are relying on the compiler to define uniform_real_distribution for you.  You will not be able to detect a difference in results between them.  All of the differences show up when you start concerning yourself with how the output of your PRNG gets mapped to [0,1).

Comment: @MoreAxes - What CortAmmon said. `uniform_real_distribution` will draw as many 32-bit values from `mt19937` as it needs to generate a single uniformly-distributed double. It's all implemented for you.